# how to get root priviliges for workstation

Tags: software-installation, permissions, root, make

Question 1: should I have to have a root privileges for installations on my personal workstation?

Question 2: If answer to Q1 is "yes", how to get root privileges on my personal workstation?

Question 3: If answer to Q1 is "no", how to complete installation if `make install` asks for creating a directory in root-controlled directory?

Problem description:

I have a problem with executing `make install`.

`make install` for installation of open-source https://github.com/RTimothyEdwards/open_pdks asks for having a /pdk directory in /usr/local/share directory which is under root control.

I tried to `mkdir pdk` and got permission error for not having root privileges.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Generally one would prefix commands with `sudo` when something needs to be done as `root`. In this case `sudo mkdir {name}` or `sudo make install`. If you need to do multiple things as `root`, you can **s**witch **u**ser with `sudo su`. Now you're `root`. When you're done, use `exit` to return to your regular user account.

Answer (score 0):

In general, root privileges are granted to you by the administrator of the system, the person(s) that have set up the workstation.

In particular, if you installed the system, you already will have root permissions. The first user created on an Ubuntu system during installation has root permissions. A user with root permissions can execute commands with these priviledges by preceding these with `sudo`, e.g. `sudo make install`.

> Question 1: should I have to have a root privileges for installations
> on my personal workstation?

If you want to install software, then, yes, you will need root privileges.

> Question 2: If answer to Q1 is "yes", how to get root privileges on my
> personal workstation?

We do not know about your situation. If you installed the system, you already have. If you did not, you will need to ask to the person that set up your system. That person may only allow you these permissions provided you are sufficiently trained in managing a Linux system. Acting as root, it is very easy to break a system if you do not know what you are doing.

If your user has root privileges, you can install software using the graphical tools. The system will ask your user password if it needs to perform an action as root. As indicated before, the `sudo` command allows you to execute a terminal command with root priviledges.

> Question 3: If answer to Q1 is "no", how to complete installation if
> make install asks for creating a directory in root-controlled
> directory?

It is clear by now that you need root permissions to modify files and directories in the system directory.

Comment: With regards to the answer to Question2, I myself installed Ubuntu on my personal workstation following the step-by-step instructions. Whom should I ask for permission?

Comment: Then you already have root permissions in the account that you created during setup as I indicated in the second paragraph..